# Maintaining Blocked user list and filtering with blocked users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am developing a talent hunting application in, for that I'm using node with mongoose in backend.
So, I need to add the block/unblock user feature. If I adds a user to blocked list from another user those two users should not appear in the search, user list etc..

I have a to filter in the following areas,

- User list api which fetches all users,
- Search module searches for particular user

Like If I block a user that user should not carry in any of my response.

My user model

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "User One",
    email: "userone@email.com",
    mobile: "1234567890",
    gender: "male"
}
```

Talent model

```
{
  _id: 1,
  categoryId: 1,
  experience: "good"
}
```

My category model

```
{
   _id: 1,
   categoryId: 1,
   experience: "good"
}
```

And I have a filter function like below

```
users = await User.aggregate([
            conditions,
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'talents',
                    as: 'talents',
                    let: { userId: '$_id' },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {
                                            $eq: ['$$userId', '$userId'],
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $in: ['$category', cat],
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
            {
                $match: {
                    talents: { $ne: [] },
                },
            },
        ]);
```

So if I create an embedded doc inside my user model like this,

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: "User One",
    email: "userone@email.com",
    mobile: "1234567890",
    gender: "male",
    blockedUsers: [{
       userId: 5,
       userId: 6
    }]
}
```

If user 1 filters the talent with above code the result should not contain user 6 and 6.

How to do this????

Comment: just pass the filter in $match `{ $expr: { $not: { $in: ["$_id", "$blockedUsers.userId"] } } }`

Comment: Getting an error like: `MongoError: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: string`

Comment: as per *So if I create an embedded doc inside my user model like this* have you created this field and having array values in all documents?

Comment: yes: `"blockedUsers": [
            {
                "_id": "600a77ce7f984d231c16d7c7",
                "userId": "600a676435bb721d6086bd72"
            }
        ]`

Comment: look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IwgjSlIKAXx) it should work.

Comment: but this works commonly for all users. I want it like according to a user. If a user filters the users in his blocked list should be filtered out.

Comment: it would be easy when you do 2 queries, first to select current users blocked userIds and second for my users list on the base of first query result blocked list userids

Comment: @turivishal this is my documents schema [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kOQHB1rVUAd)

Comment: where is current user id condition? how you will know which is current user?

Comment: @turivishal Hope you can help me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114092/geeting-commonly-available-slots-for-booking-nodejs-mogodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to execute 2 queries,

**Select current user booked users id:**

```
let currentUserID = 1;
let currentUser = await User.findOne(
  { _id: currentUserID },
  { blockedUsers: "$blockedUsers.userId", _id: 0 }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/20vtlYQhEqF)

Users list, and exclude my blocked users from list, i have corrected your query,

```
let users = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      isAdminApproved: 1,
      gender: { $in: ["male"] },
      _id: { $nin: currentUser.blockedUsers }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "talents",
      as: "talents",
      let: { userId: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            category: { $in: [1] },
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$userId", "$userId"] }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $match: { talents: { $ne: [] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZT7lXX7dVle)