# Geeting commonly available slots for booking - Nodejs mogodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create an appointment system in which the users can select a number of doctors for an appointment. The selection is based on a common timme slot from their available time slots, and from bookings.

ie, when I choose a number of doctor ids I need to give a commonly available time slots, my mongodb document are as below,

**consultant preference**

````
[{
    "_id": "60740cb3a167a82decfb0f60",
    "consultant": "605c6092d101c03c286054c7",
    "availableWeekDays": [
      {
        "slots": [
          "08:00 - 09:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00"
        ],
        "dayIndex": 1,
        "day": "monday"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 1
  },{
    "_id": "60740cd4a167a82decfb0f62"},
    "consultant": "605c609dd101c03c286054c9",
    "availableWeekDays": [
      {
        "slots": [
          "08:00 - 09:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00"
        ],
        "dayIndex": 1,
        "day": "monday"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 1
  },{
    "_id": "6074100b8eb8814b8c307a81",
    "consultant": "605c60d3d101c03c286054cb",
    "availableWeekDays": [
      {
        "slots": [
          "08:00 - 09:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00"
        ],
        "dayIndex": 2,
        "day": "tuesday"
      },
      {
        "slots": [
          "08:00 - 09:00",
          "10:00 - 11:00"
        ],
        "dayIndex": 1,
        "day": "monday"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 5
  }]```
````

**Appointment document**

```
{
    "_id": "60740cb3a167a82decfb0d21",
    "date": "2021-04-19",
    "time":"10:00 - 11:00",
    "patient":"605c60d3d101c03c28605acd"
    "consultants":[
        "605c60d3d101c03c286054cb",
        "605c609dd101c03c286054c9"
    ]
}
```

Now, if I input two consultant ids and a date I should get a response with commonly available slots for the consultants or that day index.

**Assuming the input** :

```
  {
      "date":"2021-04-19",
      "consultants":[
          "605c6092d101c03c286054c7",
          "605c60d3d101c03c286054cb"
      ]
  }
```

**Expexted result**

```
{
    "slots":["08:00 - 09:00"]
}
```

What I tried to do,

1. Find the available slots from consultant preference by specifiying the dayIndex, 1, as per above input

```
let availableSlots = [];
        for (const participant of participants) {
            const slots = await ConsultantPreferece.findOne({
                consultant: participant,
                'availableWeekDays.dayIndex': 1,
                'availableWeekDays.$': 1,
            });

            if (!slots) {
                return next(
                    new ErrorResponse('Consultant have not set any preference', 500)
                );
            }

            availableSlots.push({
                consultant: participant,
                slots: slots,
            });
        }
```

2. filter the slots with appontment slots

But I'm unable get the slots from my step 1.

Can anyne suggest a better solution???

**UPDATE**
I'm able to get the common slots of consultants from their preference like,

```
let availableSlots = [];
        for (const participant of participants) {
            const slots = await ConsultantPreferece.findOne(
                {
                    consultant: participant,
                },
                {
                    availableWeekDays: { $elemMatch: { dayIndex: 3 } }
                } ,
            );

            if (!slots) {
                return next(
                    new ErrorResponse('Consultant have not set any preference', 500)
                );
            }

            availableSlots.push(slots.availableWeekDays[0].slots);
        }

        var result = availableSlots.shift().reduce(function(res, v) {
            if (res.indexOf(v) === -1 && availableSlots.every(function(a) {
                return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
            })) res.push(v);
            return res;
        }, []);

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            availableSlots: result,
        });
```

**The output is**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "availableSlots": [
        "08:00-09:00",
        "10:00-11:00",
    ]
}
```

Now I want to loop through this slots for each consultant id and check if exists in appointment document.
if the slot is booked in appointment, it should be popped from the result array.

And I expect the last element will be the slot available for booking.

Comment: not getting your question there are confusions, 1) there is no any date in appointment as per your input   "date": "2021-12-02", 2) how do you select single slots `"slots":["08:00 - 09:00"]` there are 2 consultants id and documents and also slots array so explain this.

Comment: @turivishal hi, pls check the new edit.

Comment: what is `dayIndex = 3`?

Comment: Actually I need to extract the day number from date. For testing I. directly passed the dayIndex as 3. For the current input 2021-04-19 the dayIndex is 1

Comment: okay i am not getting your actual code but i have prepared a aggregation query may be it will help you [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zs-vwUS3rK2)

Comment: @turivishal I checked it, but if I remove slot ```08:00 - 09:00``` from consultant ```605c60d3d101c03c286054cb```  for ```dayIndex = 1``` the result will remain same rather than an empty array: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zonyYxsVqfz

Comment: its available in consultant `605c6092d101c03c286054c7`

Comment: yeah but the result im expecting is: a common slot for both consultants for the day without other apppointments

Comment: ok check [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yVTQcIApwvu) you have to write a size of consultant ids in last second $match stage, for example you are searching 2 ids of consultant then write `{ $size: 2 }` if 3 then write `{ $size: 3 }`

Comment: look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2N7skHxcq5p) updated.

Comment: @turivishal Thanks that returns all slots but I managed to modify with Nodejs. I have another question. Can you have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848324/mongodb-how-to-join-two-documents-by-key-in-second-document-and-merge-child-do/67848371#67848371)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer, but maybe someone else will find this information

The [@tspvivek/sscheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tspvivek/sscheduler) library is very good for solving the situation

You'll need to do some tweaking of the data to the type this library expects, but this is the best solution I've found